# If I turn Notifications of Group Activity to OFF, do I still see comments on my posts?

Tags: facebook-groups, facebook-notifications

If I set `Facebook Group Activity Notifications` to OFF for a group (see screenshot below) and then set `Notification Settings > Activity that Involves you` to ON and someone in that Group comments on a post I make, do I get a notification of that?

[image: group settings]

[image: notification settings]

Answer (score 1):

I tested. The answer appears to be YES.